# Django fresh login required on accessing profile page

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am new to django and writing authentication system for my application. Right now I have built the basic login/logout functionality.

What I want is that whenever a logged in user wants to access their profile page, they should be asked to confirm their password.

I have searched this on django docs but I was not able to find any resource on how to achieve. I know flask has a `fresh_login_required` decorator which does this, just wondering if it is possible to do the same thing with django as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any function for this in django. But you can write on your own with help of [**`django session`**](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions). For example:

First, we need to write a decorator:

```
# decorator

def require_fresh_login(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        has_verified_profile = request.session.pop('has_login_verified',None)
        if has_verified_profile:
             return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('fresh_password_view_url'))

  return wrap
```

Then there should be a view for `fresh_password_view_url`, where you need to put a value against key `has_login_verified` in `request.session`. For example:

```
def verify_fresh_password(request):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        if request.user.check_password(password):
           request.session['has_login_verified'] = True
           return redirect('profile_view')
    # else send error response
```